# Training time when a barrack is under upgrade

Tags: clash-of-clans

I know how the new training system works as a single queue and the calculation of training time. What I am wondering is say I have all level 6 *barracks* and the *wizards* are being trained for say *n* seconds, if I upgrade one barrack, will it increase the training time of say *wizard* or any other troop in that case until the barrack is being upgraded or will the training time be the same throughout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Just as before the update, **upgrading a barrack will increase the training time of your troops**.

Here's an example (wizards) of their training time depending on the number of barracks available :

- 1 lvl 6 barrack: 2 min training time
- 2 lvl 6 barracks: 1 min training time
- 3 lvl 6 barracks: 40 sec training time
- 4 lvl 6 barracks: 30 sec training time

Note that the training time *does not* depend on the level of the barrack.

3 lvl 6 barracks + 1 upgrading barracks = 3 available barracks = 40sec training time.

Here's the proof on my own village :

[image: One of my barracks is upgrading]

[image: The training time of my wizards is 40 sec]